# Oracle procedure insert from different sources

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, insert

I can get what am I doing wrong here

```
create or replace procedure load_category(
p_linea_cod varchar2,
p_modal_cod varchar2,
p_periodo_cod varchar2
)IS

BEGIN
  insert into category(categoryid,externalcategoryid,name)values(
  SEQ_CATEGORY.nextval,
  (select  cod_modal_est,nombre
     from modalidad_estud@ULINK
     where cod_linea_negocio = p_linea_cod
     and cod_modal_est = p_modal_cod)
  );

END;
```

I'm trying to make a simple insert with a sequence and a select statement(working statement), but can get it work, just receiving this error:

```
ORA-00947: not enough values
```

I thank your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your select returns only one column, while you're inserting three. If you need to leave them empty, add NULL values to the select, or leave the columns out of the insert field list.

[edit]

Modified query:

```
insert into category(categoryid, externalcategoryid, name)
select 
  SEQ_CATEGORY.nextval, cod_modal_est, nombre
from 
  modalidad_estud@ULINK
where 
  cod_linea_negocio = p_linea_cod
  and cod_modal_est = p_modal_cod;
```

Comment: what do you mean, the select should return values of 'cod_modal_est' and 'nombre' columns

Comment: No it doesn't, but I admit I read your query wrong. You're now inserting two values. One is the sequence, and the other is the result of the select. This will fail any way. Move the sequence into the select to solve this. (Will post example in a minute.)

Comment: Modified it. Now the query returns three columns. The *values* clause is omitted when using insert..select like this. If the select query would return more than one record, all of them would be inserted, each with their own category. Also, if it would return nothing, no rows would be inserted. You can use SQL%rowcount to get the number of affected rows after executing the insert statement.

Comment: thanks, that worked, but still curious what if i want to insert values from two different selects

Comment: Wel, you can put them together in a single select, more or less like you did now. But although there are several options, there's no generic answer to that, because it depends on the situation and the correlation between those two selects.